# Chinese poem help

Tags: translation, poetry

Im trying to express these two sentences in Chinese well.
I feel there are many ways I could do this but I want it to sound authentically Chinese.

"...,but I cannot help but love you"
Or
"...,but you will always be in my heart"

The meaning of this one is self explanatory, but this next one is a little odd.

"I hate us"

This means a hate of mankind but in the sense that we, "us", is mankind. If you are familiar with misanthropy this will make sense.

If you have any suggestions please help!

Comment: I suggest posting the entire lyric. It is difficult to stick to the central theme through reading/translating piece by piece. Also, why not to show your efforts to draw better/pointed responses.

Answer (score 1):

"but I cannot help but love you" - 但我無奈愛着你 (But I can't help but love you)

"but you will always be in my heart" - 但你常在我心間 (But you are always in my heart)

"I hate us" - 我恨人可惡 (I hate that people are abominable)

*The literal translation of "I hate us" is "我恨我們" But it is too ambiguous without the full context-- We cannot know the "us" here refers to the humankind in general or a specific group just by reading this line*

Answer (score 1):

> but I cannot help but love you

has too many buts, ruins the meter!

I cannot help but love thee.

相见情已深，未语可知心 《李白（699-762）相逢行二首》

> I hate us

Ask Chinese people to translate this and they will ask you what you mean!! It is very unchinese!

xenophobe: 仇外主义者
misanthrope: 厌恶人类的人

I hate us. (us as in everyone)
我是 个厌恶人类的人。

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot help but love you

maybe: “春情難禁盼比翼”

> i hate us

this one is . . . well, wait

Comment: 谢谢你，Under this context what does 翼 mean?

Comment: @Emma 翼 means wings: 比翼双飞. see https://baike.baidu.com/item/比翼双飞/1558502

Comment: The direct translation of "I hate us" should be "我恨我們自己", but, IMO, it is not really meant "hate" but more of "regret" or "remorse".